# Javascript Calendar rederection

Tags: javascript, calendar

I implemented this calendar on my website:
http://www.dynarch.com/projects/calendar/doc/

I want to send the user to a link if they click on a day. The link needs to contain the day:

```
<div class="DynarchCalendar-day DynarchCalendar-day-selected" dyc-date="20120420" unselectable="on" dyc-type="date">20</div>
```

I know how to toggle an event if the user clicks on a day:

```
var LEFT_CAL = Calendar.setup({
        cont     : "cont",
        fdow     : 1,
        dateInfo : getDateInfo,
        onSelect : function() {
            <!--Here-->
        }       
})
```

I can redirect the user to an other web page if they click on it:

```
window.location = "http://www.google.com/"
```

The only thing that doesn't work is that I need to add the date after the domain name. So for example:

```
window.location = "http://www.webpage.com?ShowDate=20120428"
```

Can some one show me how I can do this? The problem is that I can't get the calendar of the selected day (Class DynarchCalendar-day-selected);

Comment: please show your code in http://jsfiddle.net/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
 var LEFT_CAL = Calendar.setup({
                cont: "cont",
                weekNumbers: true,
                selectionType: Calendar.SEL_MULTIPLE,
                showTime: false,
                onSelect : function() {
                var selectedDate = $('td.DynarchCalendar-td-selected div').attr("dyc-date");
                window.location = "http://www.webpage.com?ShowDate="+selectedDate;
                }   

        })
```